# Error running vulkan with iGPU

Tags: debian, vulkan, amdgpu

When I execute `vulkaninfo` I get this following error

```
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 1.  Skipping ICD.
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 5.  Skipping ICD.
vulkaninfo: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: undefined symbol: amdgpu_query_video_caps_info
```

I tried updating the packages and I installed the following ones

```
sudo apt install vulkan-amdgpu 
sudo apt install vulkan-amdgpu-pro
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

even after updating and upgrading the packages and rebooting the system it is not working

output of `lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:57 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe67ffff
```

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics (6) @ 2.375GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir
```

Answer (score 0):

running `amdgpu-uninstall` command magically solved the problem found [here](https://github.com/lutris/lutris/issues/3541)

Comment: I guess this results in using default drivers